Web design sliders with specific alternate position
The designer asks to add a slider section on home page in following format:

I'm trying to find a way that can do this type of sliders, with:

Clicking a slide is centralizing the slide on top of other sliders,
Slides have alternating positions (see sample image below).

Here is what I've reached out (javascript, css and html):


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    
    slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
        slide.addEventListener('click', () => {
            slides.forEach(s => s.classList.remove('active'));
            slide.classList.add('active');
            updateSlides();
        });
    });
    
    function updateSlides() {
        slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
            slide.style.zIndex = 'auto';
            slide.style.transform = 'none';
            if (slide.classList.contains('active')) {
                slide.style.zIndex = 5;
                slide.style.transform = 'scale(1.2)';
            } else {
                if (index < slides.length / 2) {
                    slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-(slides.length - index - 1) * 30}%) scale(0.8)`;
                    slide.style.zIndex = slides.length - index;
                } else {
                    slide.style.transform = `translateX(${(index) * 30}%) scale(0.8)`;
                    slide.style.zIndex = index;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    updateSlides();
});
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease, z-index 0.5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid;
}

.content {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

p {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Slider Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide active">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>LOREM IPSUM 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>LOREM IPSUM 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>LOREM IPSUM 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>LOREM IPSUM 4</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>LOREM IPSUM 5</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html> 




Can you attach a sample image?

@QianZhang: attached 1 sample slide image. However the question is not about how to add image to slider. It's about alternating positions between slides and centralizing the active slide. Content come later.

What are you specifically asking? Please may you share a [mre] of the code you're using?

@evolutionxbox I'm asking for the javascript and css code

@RamiSedhom I think you should tag css

Apologies. Please keep in mind, StackOverflow is not a code-writing service, but we'll gladly help if you show what you've tried.

I'm sure there is javascript library that do that but I had searched a lot and can't find any

@evolutionxbox I added the code I'm working on it now

Are you open to using a JS library like slick or glide.js for this functionality?

@wouch yes but how to alternate the position of slides (as shown) using such libraries?

The way this is designed with slides overlapping each other will make it difficult to transition because the need to change z-index, but this example using glide.js should help you see one way that you could go about it.


let glide = new Glide('.glide', {
  type: 'carousel',
  focusAt: 'center',
  perView: 3,
  gap: -50,
  peek: {
    before: 125,
    after: 125
  }
})

glide.mount()
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  background: #737373;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 1rem;
}


/* glide.js CSS */

.glide__track,
.glide__slides {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.glide__slide {
  transition: transform 400ms ease;
}

.glide__slide.glide__slide--active {
  transform: translateY(-15px);
  z-index: 2;
}

.glide__slide:has( + .glide__slide.glide__slide--active),
.glide__slide.glide__slide--active+.glide__slide {
  transform: translateY(15px);
  z-index: 1;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>glidejs Slider Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@glidejs/glide@3.6.1/dist/css/glide.core.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slider glide">
    <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
      <div class="glide__slides">
        <div class="slide glide__slide">
          <div class="content">
            <h2>LOREM IPSUM 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide glide__slide">
          <div class="content">
            <h2>LOREM IPSUM 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide glide__slide">
          <div class="content">
            <h2>LOREM IPSUM 3</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide glide__slide">
          <div class="content">
            <h2>LOREM IPSUM 4</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide glide__slide">
          <div class="content">
            <h2>LOREM IPSUM 5</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@glidejs/glide@3.6.1/dist/glide.min.js"></script>

</html>



